# Not all GNOME Shell features present after installation

Tags: 11.10, gnome, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on VirtualBox with the following specs:

- 1024 MB RAM
- 128 VGA
- 16 HDD

Then I tried to install GNOME Shell as in [this OMG! Ubuntu post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/gnome-shell-ubuntu-11-10-guide/).

But I didn't get the same result. The shell seemed to be so basic; I didn't get hot corners, for example.

[image]

Comment: Have you ticked "3D acceleration" on the virtual machine settings?  Please dropbox (or something similar) a screenshot of your issue.

Comment: this is what i got : http://bit.ly/sxlj1e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot indicates that Gnome-Shell refused to load and has dropped back to the default *fallback* mode called Gnome-Classic.

Three specific virtualbox recommendations:

- I would recommend that you define your VirtualBox guest settings as per this picture:

  [image]
- Install VirtualBox guest additions
- I would recommend you use the very latest VirtualBox version - v4.1 at the time of writing this.

Note - it is important to check that your Host graphics card is 3D Graphics capable - This is described in this [linked VirtualBox chapter](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows Gnome Panel, which is the shell we've used in earlier versions of Ubuntu and that has been Gnomes primary shells for more than a decade. Gnome Shell is very dependent on hardware and good drivers. They're working on a version that is less hardware dependent. It might be easier to recognize by these images (it's the same desktop):

[image: Showing a customized gnome-panel desktop.]

One thing to notice is that the way you add applets and things like that has changed. You now hold super+alt and right click to show the menu in the first screenshot. You use alt+middleclick to move applets around.